# Laptop won't recognise wifi card anymore

Tags: intel-wireless

**Laptop model:** Dell latitude E6420
**Ubuntu version:** 18.04.2 LTS

My wifi was working completely fine up until last night. Now, my laptop says "no wifi adapter found" and therefore won't let me connect. I've tried turning the power off and restarting it many times. I have tried some suggestions that I've found on here and none of them work.

However my computer *is* recognising the card as it shows up when I use `lshw -C network` and `lspci`. It shows up in the terminal but the setting application says it's not there. (I was going to add the output but I don't have enough reputation to add images here yet.)

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There have been reports of people having problems when moving from the `4.15` to `4.18` Linux kernel with some Dell hardware. You'll want to manually downgrade your Linux kernel, the easiest way to do that is using the Ubuntu Update Kernel Utility (UKUU)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Now launch the `ukuu` app and select one of the `4.15` kernels to downgrade to.

Comment: I will try and find an Ethernet cable somewhere and attempt this.

Comment: You can also try rebooting and holding `Shift` and you may have a 4.15 kernel installed still.

Comment: Now it's not connecting via ethernet either.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting with an old kernel by holding `Shift` when the PC starts up?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem and it has been rectified. This was not a problem with Ubuntu or any software at all; I realised that my laptop has a physical wifi switch. It must have been bumped and turned off in my backpack and that is why I was unable to connect.